# Docker container is not launched if a particular path is used to mount a volume

Tags: docker

If I try to launch a container with the following command

```sh
docker run \
  --rm \
  -v /Users/administrator/Documents/enrico-code/code-analysis/git-metrics:/usr/src/app \
  290764/git-metrics:git-metrics
```

the container is not launched and I got the error

> sh: 1: git-metrics: not found

However, if I change the string where I mount the volume in any way, for instance if I use the following (I add `-abc` to the path of the volume) like this

```sh
-v /Users/administrator/Documents/enrico-code/code-analysis/git-metrics-abc:/usr/src/app
```

the container actually gets launched. In other words:

THE FIRST VERSION OF THE COMMAND DOES NOT WORK WHILE THE SECOND WORKS

```sh
docker run \
  --rm \
  -v /Users/administrator/Documents/enrico-code/code-analysis/git-metrics:/usr/src/app \
  290764/git-metrics:git-metrics

docker run \
  --rm \
  -v /Users/administrator/Documents/enrico-code/code-analysis/git-metrics-abc:/usr/src/app \
  290764/git-metrics:git-metrics
```

Which can be the reasons?

Comment: What's the result of `ls -la /Users/administrator/Documents/enrico-code/code-analysis`?

Comment: @Phil the result is the list of folders and files contained in `/Users/administrator/Documents/enrico-code/code-analysis`. It contains both `git-metrics`, which is a folder with content, and `git-metrics-abc`, which is an empty folder created by the `docker run -v .....` command I have launched.

Comment: Is `/usr/src/app` the directory in your image that contains your built and installed application?  Using a bind mount to hide your entire application can lead to some complex problems and I'd usually suggest deleting this `-v ...:/usr/src/app` option entirely.  What is in your image's Dockerfile?

Comment: @David Maze The app in the docker image just a wrapper around the command `npx git-metrics` which I had to do in order to overcome the fact that in some corporate laptop configurations there is no Perl, and Perl is required for the tool to run. The tool reads the code present in the folder mapped to `:/usr/src/app` and does some analysis on it. Hence the dockerfile is simpy made of these 4 lines: `FROM node:16` `WORKDIR /usr/src/app` `ENTRYPOINT ["npx", "git-metrics" ]` `CMD [ "--help" ]`

Comment: It seems like a more robust approach would be to `RUN npm install ...` in the Dockerfile and avoid the bind-mount entirely.  There are a range of problems like incorrect line endings, wrong processor architecture, missing shared libraries, and other problems that injecting code can introduce.

Comment: @David Maze The goal of the tool is to analyze code that is stored in a folder of a developer's machine. How could I read such code from within a container without mounting the folder as an external volume? I am not familiar with docker so any help would be very much appreciated. By the way, I could run `npm run install ...` but that would not solve the problem that I have to read from the local drive from within docker.